# How to modify comment-wrapper.tpl.php to change the comment form layout?

Tags: theming, comments

I am trying to change the layout of my comment form. Unfortunately, when I print only fields that I need and the submit button, I can't use the button, nothing happens when I press on it.

I used following code in comment-wrapper.tpl.php:

```
<div id="comment-rating">
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_cuisine']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_service']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_ambiance']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_accueil']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_qualit_']); ?>
  </div>

  <div id="comment-text">
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_nom']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_n_de_carte']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_e_mail']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_t_l_phone_']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['comment_body']); ?>
  </div>
  <?php print render($content['comment_form']['actions']); ?>
```

Everything is displayed as expected, but i can't submit the form.

I also tried something like:

```
<div id="comment-rating">
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_cuisine']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_service']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_ambiance']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_accueil']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_qualit_']); ?>
  </div>

  <div id="comment-text">
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_nom']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_n_de_carte']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_e_mail']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['field_t_l_phone_']); ?>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']['comment_body']); ?>
  </div>
  <?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
```

Like that I can submit the form by pressing on button, but the content of fields are not taken in consideration.

Answer (score 2):

## The best solution:

This is the default `comment-wrapper.tpl.php`:

```
  <?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
    <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('Add new comment'); ?></h2>
    <?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to modify the form elements by overriding the template file, here is **the best known way**:

```
  <?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
    <h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('Add new comment'); ?></h2>

    <?php
    // 1. Create a custom markup
    $form_custom_markup = '';
    $form_custom_markup .= '<div style="background-color: red;">';
    $form_custom_markup .= render($content['comment_form']['author']);
    $form_custom_markup .= '</div>';
    $form_custom_markup .= '<div style="background-color: blue;">';
    $form_custom_markup .= render($content['comment_form']['comment_body']);
    $form_custom_markup .= '</div>';

    // 2. Attach the custom markup to the form
    $content['comment_form']['custom_markup'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $form_custom_markup
    );
    ?>

    <?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

In this example we make the Author field appear in red background and the comment body in blue background!

You could simply modify the sample above to re-arrange any form element in your form.

## Why the normal way didn't work?

To understand this solution and other solutions first we need to understand why `forms` behave differently than other `render arrays`.

To start let us have a look at the function that renders a form:

```
<?php
// form.inc

function theme_form($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#action'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['action'] = drupal_strip_dangerous_protocols($element['#action']);
  }
  element_set_attributes($element, array('method', 'id'));
  if (empty($element['#attributes']['accept-charset'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['accept-charset'] = "UTF-8";
  }
  // Anonymous DIV to satisfy XHTML compliance.
  return '<form' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '><div>' . $element['#children'] . '</div></form>';
}
```

As you see, when you `render($form)` it wraps it with ''. It means that any elements that have been rendered before will be out of `<form>`. That was why when you render `render($form['actions'])` before `render($form)` even buttons stop working, because they are out of the `<form>` element!

## What are other solutions?

### Using HOOK_preprocess_hook()

As you could see we modified $content['comment_form']. You could do the same thing by using the `template preprocess function`:

```
/**
 * Implements HOOK_preprocess_hook()
 * Preprocess variables for comment-wrapper.tpl.php
 */
function THEME_preprocess_comment_wrapper(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'article') {

    $form_custom_markup = '';
    $form_custom_markup .= '<div style="background-color: green;">';
    $form_custom_markup .= render($vars['content']['comment_form']['author']);
    $form_custom_markup .= '</div>';
    $form_custom_markup .= '<div style="background-color: red;">';
    $form_custom_markup .= render($vars['content']['comment_form']['comment_body']);
    $form_custom_markup .= '</div>';

    // Attach the custom markup to the form
    $vars['content']['comment_form']['custom_markup'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $form_custom_markup
    );
  }
}
```

This example overrides form elements of comment form on `article` pages.

**Tip:** You should replace `THEME` with your theme name and put this function in `template.php` in you theme folder.

### Using HOOK_preprocess_hook()

If you trace where the element is actually generated you will get to this lines in `comment.module`:

```
$build = drupal_get_form("comment_node_{$node->type}_form", (object) array('nid' => $node->nid));
$additions['comment_form'] = $build;
```

We can see this is a form with the `form_id` of `comment_node_NODE_TYPE_form`. So we could use `hook_form_alter` to alter form elements:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'comment_node_article_form') {
    // Play around with $form
  }
}
```

In this example we are altering the comment form for `article` nodes.

**Tip:** Generally using `form_alter` to change the display of the form is not recommended because it also affects the `form_submit()` and `form_validate()` and may cause unwanted issues in future or conflict with other modules.